# Display result if text matches data in an XML file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I currently have an XML file where information is saved when text data is submitted. I also have a TextBox and Button for users to search for the information they submitted.

As an example, I want the users to be able to search a registration number, and once they press the search button the result will only display if it is an exact match. I currently have the XML data bound through a GridView, and I am currently using an unfinished if/else statement for the search part, however the data will not display on the client side unless I input the exact data in the if/else statement. What options are there to correct this?

**This is the C#**

```
protected void Searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds;
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/RegData.xml");
    ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(filepath);
    RES.DataSource = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
    RES.DataBind();

    var sr = Searchreg.Text;
    var dss = Convert.ToString(ds);
    if (sr.Equals("12345678"))
    {
        RES.DataSource = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
    }
    else
    {
        none.Visible = true;
        RES.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**And this is from the aspx page**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Searchreg"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
      <td>
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Searchbutton" Text="Search" OnClick="Searchbutton_Click" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="RES" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Registration" DataField="Registration" />
            </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
      </td>
      <td>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="none" Text="No Results" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**This is an example from the XML file:**

```
<registration>
    <own>
        <Name>afadf</Name>
        <Address>afaf</Address>
        <Number>adfad</Number>
        <Registration>12345678</Registration>
        <BoatLength>adfd</BoatLength>
        <ManufacturerYear>adf</ManufacturerYear>
        <LeaseStart>16/06/2016</LeaseStart>
        <LeaseEnd>24/06/2016</LeaseEnd>
        <Cost>Total Cost: $40</Cost>
    </own>
    <lease></lease>
</registration>
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what exactly what you're trying to do. Why are you comparing the `sr` string to a constant value? Are you trying to search the XML file for this `sr` value? Perhaps if we knew what the XML file looked like it would help.

Comment: I'll add the XML file in a second,

I want to be able to search what's in the XML file and display the results, but only if the result is an exact match

Comment: Not letting me post the xml up there so i'll post it here

<registration>
  
    <own>
      <Name>afadf</Name>
      <Address>afaf</Address>
      <Number>adfad</Number>
      <Registration>12345678</Registration>
      <BoatLength>adfd</BoatLength>
      <ManufacturerYear>adf</ManufacturerYear>
      <LeaseStart>16/06/2016</LeaseStart>
      <LeaseEnd>24/06/2016</LeaseEnd>
      <Cost>Total Cost: $40</Cost>
    </own>
  
  <lease>
  </lease>
</registration>

Answer (score 0):

You could supply [`RowFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) to `DataTable`

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "registration = " + Searchreg.Text; // use correct column name.
RES.DataSource = = dv;
```